# Using QUnit to test utility functions that use document.write(): Make document object be some other document?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, qunit, document.write

I have a pair of utility functions that use `document.write()` to alter the DOM, injecting tags that load JavaScript and CSS.

Is it possible to use QUnit to test that the injection is happening correctly without having it impact the actual DOM of the test results page?

I can:

- Overwrite `document.write()`, perhaps in `setup` and resetting it in `teardown`, to be a function I define. But them I'm not testing that the calls to `document.write()` do what they're supposed to do.
- Use something like js-test-driver to have the JavaScript run from a command line (although I really want to have the test results page available).
- Create a separate test results page just for these utility tests so that those results don't affect the other tests in any way, shape, or form (although I really want a single unified page).
- Pass the utility functions empty JS and CSS files to load so they don't actually impact the results page.

So I have options.

**But what I really want** is to make `document` be some document other than the actual current document.  I'm not sure this is possible. (In fact, I'm not even sure it makes any sense.)  Is this possible?  It seems like something I might be able to do with an iframe or something like that.

If it helps at all, here's an example of the type of function I want to unit test:

```
function(jsFile){
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+jsFile+'"></script>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I don't need to test `document.write()`.  I merely need to test that my code is sending something expected to `document.write()`.  So I went with the first option above, redefining `document.write()` temporarily in the `setup()` and `teardown()` for the test.